# Hyperledger Explorer started with a problem

Tags: hyperledger

This is my issue log
[2023-10-27T21:02:14.356] [ERROR] main - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
at setTimeout (timers.js:122:11)
at Timeout.handleDisconnect [as _onTimeout] (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/postgreSQL/PgService.js:106:5)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}
[2023-10-27T21:08:59.575] [INFO] PgService - SSL to Postgresql disabled
[2023-10-27T21:08:59.575] [INFO] PgService - connecting to Postgresql postgres://postgres:******@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
[2023-10-27T21:08:59.593] [ERROR] PgService - error when connecting to db: error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
at Connection.parseE (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
at Connection.parseMessage (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
at Socket. (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
name: 'error',
length: 104,
severity: 'FATAL',
code: '28P01',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: undefined,
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'auth.c',
line: '330',
routine: 'auth_failed'
}
[2023-10-27T21:09:00.070] [INFO] Platform -  client_configs.name  first-network  client_configs.profile  ./connection-profile/first-network.json
[2023-10-27T21:09:00.071] [ERROR] FabricClient - TypeError: Cannot read property 'organization' of undefined
at FabricConfig.getOrganization (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/FabricConfig.js:82:29)
at FabricConfig.isFabricCaEnabled (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/FabricConfig.js:61:20)
at FabricGateway.initialize (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/gateway/FabricGateway.js:49:44)
at FabricClient.initialize (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/FabricClient.js:63:29)
at Object.createFabricClient (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/utils/FabricUtils.js:32:16)
at Platform.buildClients (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/Platform.js:126:37)
at Platform.initialize (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/Platform.js:71:14)
at Explorer.initialize (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/Explorer.js:113:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async startExplorer (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/main.js:116:2)
[2023-10-27T21:09:00.073] [ERROR] main - <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[2023-10-27T21:09:00.073] [ERROR] main - Error :  [ 'Invalid platform configuration, Please check the log' ]
[2023-10-27T21:09:01.595] [ERROR] PgService - error when connecting to db: TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
at Timeout.handleDisconnect [as _onTimeout] (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/postgreSQL/PgService.js:89:16)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
[2023-10-27T21:09:01.597] [ERROR] main - <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Explorer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
[2023-10-27T21:09:01.597] [ERROR] main - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined
at setTimeout (timers.js:122:11)
at Timeout.handleDisconnect [as _onTimeout] (/root/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/app/persistence/postgreSQL/PgService.js:106:5)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK'
}

I tried to open the browser, Hyperledger Explorer with port 8080, but there was no response.I think if this problems are solved, the web page should open normally.